# Android design- Data sync approach

Tags: android, sqlite, service, alarm

I have following scenario:

Android application running on mobile device needs to have data syncing feature based on given set of interval specified by mobile application user.

I have designed a UI which will accept syncing frequency from user and persist in `sqlite` db. I was wondering what would be right approach for building syncing logic. Server exposes restfull webservice for getting delta changes in data. Syncing should happen even if application is in dormant( application is not active) Background syncing should be invoked on specified frequency.

Can i use make use service along alarm for implementing this?
Is there a better approach for implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) class, a Service, AlarmManager, and every component that follows from using the SyncAdapter class.

Using a SyncAdapter allows the user to control the syncing from the same place he controls the accounts and the syncing of all his other apps: google apps, facebook, twitter, whatsapp, etc.

This is really the best way to do syncing. It's part of the standard UI the user is used to. And it's also the most energy efficient way you can do syncing.

Also, using a SyncAdapter doesn't preclude you from having the user set the frequency of the Syncs inside your app (as long as the primary way of turning on and off the syncing still goes through the "Accounts and Sync" main settings of the device itself).

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen, I was thinking to use AlarmManger along with Service class , without making use of SyncAdapter. the reason is,I have specific restfull service exposed by Server,with security as open SSL. I am worried if I use SyncAdapter built in feature i may run into trouble. I am going to use service class to implement code to fetch data .This service class will be invoked by AlarmManager on a specified frequency. After receiving response from the server i can notify Activity with data , which will show the fresh data  recieved from server on UI . Am i making correct approach here ??

Comment: "I have specific restfull service exposed by Server,with security as open SSL." This won't be a problem with the SyncAdapter. For instance, all the Google Apps use SSL and oauth authentication by default. The SyncAdapter is the most correct approach. You should check out the Udacity course called Android App Fundamentals by Reto Meier from Google, lesson 6 especially (you'll need to register on Udacity, but if you press the blue button to access the course materials for free, you won't need to enter a credit card number). https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/